# Can't use python VLC, as the path to VLC is unchangeable

Tags: python, windows, path, vlc

I'm planning to use python-VLC in a script of mine, yet I cant seem to get anything past the import statement!

My code consists of simply importing VLC and creating an instance, yet python throws an error.

```
    import vlc
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 210, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()[0], "X:\0Utilities\VLC"
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 164, in find_lib
    os.chdir(plugin_path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'A:\\VLC'
```

My installation of VLC is not in my A drive, because I do not have an A drive.

Here is my python code however it isn't that helpful, as it is only two lines

```
import vlc

player=vlc.Instance()
```

Comment: You must have some remains of previous tries, the paths that are shown in the log are really strange and the python bindings cannot make them up, so they  come from either your registry or environment variables. Clean the windows registry, and check your environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem earlier, installed 64-bit VLC player but found out that I had 32-bit Python installed. Check to make sure they are both 64-bit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26547819)

Comment: On the contrary, It is an answer nonetheless. I understand it is not worthy of a full answer @Ehsan but seeing as he cant comment due to his reputation, the only thing he could do was submit an answer. After all, stackoverflow is about helping people, not correcting people on how to help eachother. Thank you user <3